# How to retrieve double data using intent?

Tags: java, android-intent, double

I am trying to pass double data to another activity via this code :

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String sChicken = Double.toString(chicken);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseBurger.this,com.example.burgerjoint.ChooseDrinks.class);
            intent.putExtra("chicken",sChicken);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Data is passing properly but I am unable to retrieve using this code : (I get error in the first line trying to run the app with debugger)

```
String sChicken = intent.getStringExtra("chicken");
    Double chicken = Double.parseDouble(sChicken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Double sChicken = 4555.667; // your Double value

        Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseBurger.this,com.example.burgerjoint.ChooseDrinks.class);
        intent.putExtra("chicken",sChicken);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

In Second or reciever activity something like this

```
Double value = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("chicken",0.00); //0.00 is default value
```